# How to put the selected options in an array depends on user selection?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I want to get the value of selected options and create an array using AJAX. I have this code,

```
<select class="form-control" name="cols[]" multiple="multiple" id="cols[]" required="required">
  <option value="val1">uploaded to webgis</option>
  <option value="val2">Remarks on upload</option>
  <option value="val3">Level of Approval</option>
  <option value="val4">Date Approved</option>
  <option value="val5">Year Approved</option>
</select>
```

how am I going to put it in an array using **AJAX**? for example, the user selected the *val4* then next is *val5* then next is *val1*. what i want to achieve is to sort them depends on user selection, array(val4, val5, val1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) to capture the event of change of the select after the change happens get all the selected option value then use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

```js
$('.form-control').change(function() {
  var optionvalue = $("option:selected", this).map(function() {
    return this.value
  }).get().join(", ");

  console.log(optionvalue)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="cols[]" multiple="multiple" id="cols[]" required="required">
  <option value="val1">uploaded to webgis</option>
  <option value="val2">Remarks on upload</option>
  <option value="val3">Level of Approval</option>
  <option value="val4">Date Approved</option>
  <option value="val5">Year Approved</option>
</select>
```

Try this way

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'll try your answer.

Comment: I would like to know, could you explain the flow of the script above your answer :)

Comment: @EnEel pls check my explanation hope it is clear enough